# Blank sharing modal on EveryPlay

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, everyplay

The title says it all. I have implemented EveryPlay in my game. Runs fine on android , but on iOS when I display the sharing modal it's blank. I'm testing on a Ipad and the configuration of everplay is correct. Anyone else experiencing this problem? I tried updating to the newest package that was released on 10th of August but that did not help.

Edit : Modal seems to work on a iPod and iPhone. The only problem is with a iPad.

Comment: title says blak? i guess you want to say blank

Comment: @Syed yes , sorry I misspelled  it .